# Looping through the ArrayList of Model Class in Vb.net

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, vb.net, view, arraylist

I have an arraylist, that contains model class objects. Here is how I create the array list.

```
Dim arr As New ArrayList
Dim citizenHelper As New CitizensHelper
While dr.Read
    Dim appointment As New Appointment
    appointment.AppointmentId = dr("appointment_id")
    appointment.DoctorNin = dr("doctor_nin")
    appointment.DoctorName = citizenHelper.getNameByNin(dr("doctor_nin"))
    appointment.PatientNin = dr("patient_nin")
    appointment.PatientName = citizenHelper.getNameByNin(dr("patient_nin"))
    appointment.BookingDate = dr("booking_date")
    If dr("cancelled") Is "1" Then
        appointment.Cancelled = True
    End If
    If dr("active") Is "1" Then
        appointment.Active = True
    End If
    arr.Add(appointment) 'I add to the array like this
End While
ViewData("row") = arr
```

I want to use this arraylist to generate a table of records on the view page. I tried using a for loop but I cannot access the model values like that. So please tell me, how i can solve this?

I tried doing something like this

```
<% For Each ap As ArrayList In ViewData("row")%>
    <tr>
        <td>
            ...... <!-- Now I want to show those value from a table here -->
        </td>
    </tr>
<% Next ap%>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use

```
<% For Each ap As Appointment In ViewData("rows") As ArrayList %>
<tr>
    <td>
        ...... <!-- Now I want to show those value from a table here -->
    </td>
</tr>
<% Next ap%>
```

The ViewData("rows") contains the ArrayList so we need to iterate this collection, and the ArrayList contains the data of `Appointment` type.

Comment: You can get the Appointment with the namespace of model class i.e. **SolutionName.Models.Appointment**

Answer (score 0):

first idea:

typo? `ViewData("row")` vs. `ViewData("rows")` ?